# Point-free function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree, monomorphism-restriction

How do one define this point-free?

```
let argmax m = (fst.(maximumBy (comparing snd)).(zip [0..])) m
```

which works as expected.
The most logical seems to just drop the `m` like this:

```
let argmax = (fst.(maximumBy (comparing snd)).(zip [0..]))
```

Works to define in ghci, but calling it with `argmax [1,3,4,5,6,1]` gives me

```
<interactive>:103:9:
    No instance for (Num ())
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `argmax', namely `[1, 3, 4, 5, ....]'
    In the expression: argmax [1, 3, 4, 5, ....]
```

I think it has to do with the types:

```
:t (fst.(maximumBy (comparing snd)).(zip [0..]))
:: (Enum c, Num c, Ord a) => [a] -> c
```

for the point version:

```
argmax :: (Enum c, Num c, Ord a) => [a] -> c
```

for the point-free version:

```
argmax :: [()] -> Integer
```

Is this a ghci spookiness or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's the monomorphism restriction. If you define it without arguments, it gets a monomorphic type, and ghci defaults - since there are no constraints - to `()`. Disable the monomorphism restriction `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, give a type signature, or define it with an argument.

Comment: Oh, and it's been asked before, let me find a duplicate.

Comment: Just as a pointer, you don't need most of the parens: `argmax = fst . maximumBy (comparing snd) . zip [0..]` will work fine.